# TenantEncryptionCert on VM created in Azure

Tags: azure, iis, certificate, ssl-certificate, virtual-machine

I created Azure VM with SQL Server pre-installed and configured IIS to run my .NET application on it. When configuring SSL for my app I noticed that there are many certificates present on server already and quite a few of them being **TenantEncryptionCert** issued by and for Windows Azure CRP Certificate Generator. Does anyone have any idea what are these certificates for? Are these some Azure specific certs without which I will lose connectivity to my VM or what? Can I use them for SSL?

[image: Azure VM certificates]

Comment: Also just found this, and the server is not happy about our cert situation. Any updates?

Comment: No, but I believe that these are some certs for Azure to track health and status of Azure services - in this case VM. But this is only my opinion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***TenantEncryptionCert*** certificates are used by the Azure Guest Agent (GA) & extensions.

You’ll usually see it when extensions are using Protected Settings like passwords, and we need to securely transfer the payloads with the WireServer (the host node). 
So they are encrypted and a certificate is needed.

The certificate is automatically created and managed by the GA. You shouldn’t really care about it.

GA checks for the presence of certificate on startup / update. If you delete it, or if it’s not there for other reasons, then it’ll create a new one.

Note that the GA doesn’t clean the expired certificates… so you might end up with a lot of certs in the certmgr console. For this reason you can safely delete the expired ones.

HTH

Comment: I am getting one generated every day.  This cant be normal.