# How to create TenantEncryptionCert in IIS on Azure VM?

Tags: azure, iis, certificate

I want to create TenantEncryptionCert in IIS's Server Certificates.

I want to know the create step by step.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As Rossano Vitulli-MSFT says in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44671396/7609093). The TenantEncryptionCert certificates are used by the Azure Guest Agent (GA) & extensions.

The certificate is automatically created and managed by the GA.GA checks for the presence of certificate on startup / update. If you delete it, or if it’s not there for other reasons, then it’ll create a new one.